# c# UTF8 GetString from bytes array not equal to php chr function

Tags: c#, php, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to make one decoder. Basic system .Net 4.7 I'm trying to migrate this system into php, but I'm having trouble converting bytes. As far as I understand the default string **UTF-16le** on **C#**, I understood the **ord** and **chr** functions as **UCS-2** on the **PHP** side. I want to do below and I do not get the same result there are codes. What can I do to fix this, thanks in advance

```
XOR Encoded Text Bytes = [101,107,217,78,40,68,234,218,162,67,139,81,44,166,24,148];
```

on **C#**

```
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(destinationArray);
```

On **PHP**

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($encoded);$i++){
            echo "\t".$encoded[$i]." => ".chr($encoded[$i])."\n";
            $tmpStr .= chr($encoded[$i]);
        }
```

**C#** Result size=26:

```
ek�N(D�ڢC�Q,��
```

**PHP** Result size=16:

```
ek�N(D�ڢC�Q,��
```

the strings looks the same, but byte translation is quite different.

**C#** Result to Bytes array:

```
byte[] utf8 = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(result);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", utf8));
```

> response =
>   101-0-107-0-253-255-78-0-40-0-68-0-253-255-162-6-67-0-253-255-81-0-44-0-253-255-24-0-253-255

**PHP** Result to Bytes Array:

```
echo implode("-",unpack("C*", $tmpStr));
```

> response = 101-107-217-78-40-68-234-218-162-67-139-81-44-166-24-148

if php response convert to UTF-16le, results again different

```
echo implode("-",unpack("C*", mb_convert_encoding($tmpStr,'UTF-16le')));
```

> response =
>   101-0-107-0-63-0-78-0-40-0-68-0-63-0-162-6-67-0-63-0-81-0-44-0-63-0-24-0-63-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing quite different things here.

First, in the C# code, you are not using the same encoding when converting from bytes to a string and then from a string back to bytes: `Encoding.UTF8` in the first case and `Encoding.Unicode` (which is .NET name for `UTF-16`) in the latter... Things cannot go well if you do this. And by the way, I'm not sure that PHP's `UCS2` is equivalent to `UTF-16`:

- [`UTF-8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encodes characters on 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes depending on the character
- [`UTF-16`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encodes characters on 2 or 4 bytes depending on the character
- [`UCS-2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Coded_Character_Set) always encodes characters on 2 bytes, and hence cannot encode more than 65536 characters...

Then what you pass to the 'bytes to string' conversions is not necessarily valid! Because you've XORed the input data (I assume it to be some secret string), the resulting bytes may or may not be a valid sequence in some encodings. For example:

- It is not valid in [`ASCII`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) because you have (in your example) bytes > 127
- It is not valid in `UTF-8` because 217 followed by 78 is recognized neither as a 1-, 2-, 3-, or 4-byte character by `UTF-8`; hence, the � you see before the N.
- It seems to be invalid `UTF-16` as well, but roundtripping works (I could get back the original array using .NET's `Unicode.GetString`, then `Unicode.GetBytes`. If I remove your last byte - and end up with an odd number of bytes - then `UTF-16` roundtripping does not work any more...
- Although I did not test it, it should also be invalid `UCS-2` because `UCS-2` 'looks like' `UTF-16` for 2-byte characters.
- Roundtripping works with [`ANSI`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_character_set) encodings sucha as [`windows-1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) because these encodings accept any byte. However, I would discourage using such trick because you have to be sure the same code page is used on both sides of the encoding/decoding process.

Therefore, I think, in your case, the best way to store your XORed bytes into a string would be to convert the array to base64. In C# you can do it this way:

```cs
// The code below gives you ZWt1TihEInY+QydRLEIYMA==
var converted = Convert.ToBase64String(array); 
// And this one gives you back the initial array
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(converted);
```

Quick googling will tell you to use `base64_encode` and `base64_decode` in PHP.

---

Bottom note: if you want to **really** understand what's going on with al this encodings stuff, here is the must-read blog post on the subject: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: yes If both systems were mine, I could store the bytes as base64, but the silverlight application was made with [c # and it connects to an IIS 7 Server where it is authorized with a username and password.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kR37Dy) I have redesigned this system with php to use it independently of the desktop application on my side with php. I debugged the silverlight application, I took the hash function of the password and I wanted to implement it with php, but I want to solve this byte2string after the correct xor encryption.

Comment: **Problem Solved**  @odalet thank you for answering, problem solved by itself :). I didn't make any changes to the PHP code, I just upgraded the PHP version of the server from 7.2 to 7.3. I'm afraid to try and drop the PHP version again and leave it as it is :). [PHP Code](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ag0m-xsvr)